# Core Data - failing to load data, entity not found

Tags: ios, core-data

I have created a simple 1 entity data model through Core Data. I add an entity in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" of "AppDelegate". Then, I am trying to load the data of the model to an array and then a table view. 
I am aware that there are similar post, but I still can't find out whats wrong with my code.

- List of things I have tried and checked:
- The entity is added properly into the model
- I have already checked the entity names and they are correct.
- I have tried deleting the app and clean rebuilding it but still nothing.

So there must be a more major issue with my code. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'FavoritesInfo'
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "favTable.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) favTable *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;


@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory; // reference files for core data


@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
  #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    @synthesize window = _window;
    @synthesize viewController = _viewController;
    @synthesize navController = _navController;

    @synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
    @synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
    @synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;



    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *favoritesInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FavoritesInfo"
                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [favoritesInfo setValue:@"Product 1" forKey:@"name"];
        [favoritesInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15] forKey:@"score"];


        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }


        return YES;
    }
```

Then in the class of the table viewcontroller favtable.h

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


    @interface favTable : UITableViewController  <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> 
    {
        NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

        NSArray *favArr;
        int num;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *favArr;


    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;


    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

    @end
```

**favtable.m** viewdidload

```
#import "favTable.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface favTable ()

@end

@implementation favTable

@synthesize favArr;
@synthesize spVC;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController;




- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Favorites";

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"FavoritesInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];



      NSError *error=nil;

    self.favArr=[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@" fetchError=%@,details=%@",error,error.userInfo); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the managed object context on the view controller? Does it exist?

Comment: You are right. I included this in my table class but still the same error.  self.managedObjectContext = ((ecoAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;

Comment: Where do you include that line (show that code and the method it's in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your managedObjectContext is not set in your ViewController. 
Set it in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, usually looks like:

```
ViewControllerClass *controller = (ViewControllerClass*)self.window.rootViewController;
```

or with a navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
ViewControllerClass *controller = (ViewControllerClass *)navigationController.topViewController;
```

And then:

```
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: Your solution causes problems to my code. I do not have only these 2 view controllers in my app. [ViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d638c0

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My answer was that you didn't set the managedObjectContext for your viewController and I offered you two examples. Your own code below is a third one, each has it's own merit.

Comment: You are right its another solution. Thats why I ll accept it

Comment: That's nice, thank you - but I didn't mean it like this. I just thought the core of your problem was the missing managedObjectContext, not necessarily how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

In my favtable.m class I added this to set the managedObjectContext and it works properly.

```
self.managedObjectContext = ((AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: Can you add some description as to why this fixed the problem, and what exactly the problem was that it fixed?  Thanks